# Which of the following is one-to-one?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If $f$ and $g$ are bijective functions on $[0,1]$,then which of the following is one-to-one on $[0,1]$?

$$\sqrt{g},f+g,f-g,f\circ g,g\circ f,\frac{f^2+g^2}{2}$$

My try:I have easily proved that $\sqrt{g},f\circ g,g\circ f$ are one-to-one.

$f+g$ is not one-to-one,take $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=1-x$.

$f-g$ is not one-to-one,take $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x$.

My problem:I have problem about the last part to prove or disprove it.

**Edit**: Actually the problem is that $f^2(x)=(f(x))^2$ or $f^2(x)=f\circ f(x)$,I think it should be  $f^2(x)=f\circ f(x)$

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: The $f^2 + g^2$ suggests a certain identity involving well-known functions.

Comment: One counterexample: $f(x) = \sqrt x$ and $g(x) = \sqrt{1 - x}$.

Comment: @Tunococ $f^2(x)=f\circ f (x)$

Comment: @Travis $f^2(x)=f\circ f (x)$ it is not the $f^2(x)=(f(x))^2$

Comment: I suppose taken that way $f^2 + g^2$ is ambiguous, but I've never seen $f^2 + g^2$ (without the positioning of $(x)$ for emphasis) denote what you say it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $s_1 = \frac 14, s_2 = \frac 24, s_3 = \frac 34$ and $S = \{s_1, s_2, s_3\}$. Define the following function:
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
s_2 & ; x = s_1 \\
s_3 & ; x = s_2 \\
s_1 & ; x = s_3 \\
x & ; x \in [0, 1] - S
\end{cases}
$$
Then $g = f \circ f$ is defined by
$$
g(x) =
\begin{cases}
s_3 & ; x = s_1 \\
s_1 & ; x = s_2 \\
s_2 & ; x = s_3 \\
x & ; x \in [0, 1] - S
\end{cases}
$$
It follows that $f = g \circ g$. Therefore, $h = f \circ f + g \circ g = f + f \circ f$ is given by
\begin{align}
h(x) & =
\begin{cases}
s_2 + s_3 & ; x = s_1 \\
s_1 + s_3 & ; x = s_2 \\
s_1 + s_2 & ; x = s_3 \\
2x & ; x \in [0, 1] - S
\end{cases} \\
& =
\begin{cases}
\frac 54 & ; x = \frac 14 \\
\frac 44 & ; x = \frac 24 \\
\frac 34 & ; x = \frac 34 \\
2x & ; x \in [0, 1] - S
\end{cases} \\
\therefore \quad
h\left(\frac 38\right) & = \frac 34 = h\left(\frac 34\right).
\end{align}
This shows that $h$ is not injective, and nor is $h/2$.